# PCA for Time Series with Different Frequency in R

Tags: r, time-series, pca

I am trying to perform the Principal Component Analysis in R on my dataset. My dataset consists of time series data with different frequencies. For example, I could have x1 in quarter ending (Mar, Jun, Sep, Dec) and x2 in monthly (Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr....). Before performing the PCA, is it best to standardize them into either monthly/quarterly?